# Debezium - Problem concerning a DATE type in MariaDB

Tags: date, mariadb, debezium

I am using Debezium with a MariaDB database, I have a problem when it comes to a date type field to capture, Debezium convert it into TimeStamp but with an incorrect value, for example for a value of 26/05/2008 which must be 1211752800 in TImestamp, Debezium converted it to a value of 14025.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What internal format does Debezium use for "dates"?

Comment: 14025 smells like the number of weeks from 1/1/0001.

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely correct - please take a look at https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.9/connectors/mysql.html#data-types

The excerpt from the docs

> DATE    INT32   io.debezium.time.Date Represents the number of days since epoch.

So what you see is number of days since Unixe epoch date